# admob smart banner on part of screen

Tags: android, admob, smartbanner

I want to put an admob smart banner at the bottom of my app.
I know for sure I can put a banner at the bottom that will be in the full width of the screen in landscape mode like this:
[image: v1]

Though I want to put my smart banner to be only at the bottom of the fragment, and my question is, **is it valid or is it against admob policy to put the banner like this**? Does it have to cover the whole width?
[image: v2]

**so is version 2 is valid?**

Comment: here is link for discouraged banner implementation policy https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214

Comment: it doesn't say that banner needs to be full width but i believe its very close to buttons and might violate policy of accidental clicks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend for you to use the native ad format for this as you can choose to adapt it to your layout and place it wherever you want. More information here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start